# Is it possible to detect onFocus of a RadioGroup?

Tags: android, radio-button, onfocus

I have an activity with a number of radio groups each with radio buttons. I can't seem to catch onfocusChanged event for the radiogroup. I have tried using onFocusChangeListener, (which works fine on EditText fields), but not for RadioGroups. I want to ensure I can detect tap events when the user either enters a radio group or taps away into another field.

Is it possible to detect entry into/out of a radio group ? (Note that I do NOT need to detect "onCheckChanged"). If so, can you please provide a simple code sample or reference.

Comment: What other views might be consuming the touch before `onFocusChangeListener` has a chance to hear it?

Comment: There is an edittext field as well, which also has it's own onFocusChangeListener.